# Jupyter notebook cannot convert correctly for inline or html markdown

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I was trying a pynb and found it's not working properly, what should I do to convert the above to the below? Maybe it's a reason of parse_html and parse_inline, but I don't know how to operate the environment.
[The above inline **x.copy_(y)** is not executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMV9s.png)
I first try this in jupyterlab, but seems notebook is not working too.

````
<div class="alert alert-info"><h4>Note</h4><p>Any operation that mutates a tensor in-place is post-fixed with an ``_``.
    For example:  (```x.copy_(y)```), ``x.t_()``, will change ``x``.</p></div>

You can use standard NumPy-like indexing with all bells and whistles!

```x.copy_(y)```, ``x.t_()``, will change ``x``
````

Comment: After ^^^^ and ~~~~ things are not working in the same way.

Comment: Test on the followings as the starting codes are not working:
%env parse_html=True
%env parse_inline_html=True
%env parse_block_html=True